# .htaccess mod_rewrite for https://subdomain.domain.com to https://www.subdomain.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file for redirecting my domain permanently

from

https://domain.com

to

https://www.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How should I mod_rewrite for redirecting my sub-domain

from

https://subdomain.domain.com

to

https://www.subdomain.domain.com

I mean how can I redirect 3rd level domain from `https://` to `https://www.` using .htaccess mod_rewrite?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first rule to the following. This should redirect the browser to the correct url in 1 hop. In the second condition we match `www.` if it is in front of the url, or nothing in the first capture group, and all that is left in the second capture group. This may seem counter-intuitive, but this makes sure that we don't have `www.` twice in front of the url, but also be be able to prepend `www.` to the hostname if it isn't already there. `RewriteRule ^` is just a fancy way of writing "Match everything" (or: "Match every string that begins", which is even the case for an empty string).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then you need a second rule to handle requests that are already on https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: the mod_rewrite isn't working. It can't redirect the url and displays certificate error. thanks,

Comment: That is not a problem with `mod_rewrite`, that's a problem with your certificate. More specific: Your certificate is probably for `sub.example.com` and you get a warning that the site has an invalid certificate when you try to use it for `www.sub.example.com`.

Comment: @anubhava all the certificates were issued in favour of my domains and sub-domains with www. prefix. i don't receive any error when redirect my domain `https:// to https://www.`using the code i posted in my question. the problem occurs only when i redirect my sub-domains. any idea?

Comment: Then your certificate only works for `www.*.example.com`, `www.example.com` and `example.com`? What anubhava says is that your browser *will* check the validity of the certificate when a request to `https://sub.example.com` is made. This even happens when no rewrites are defined. The certificate is invalid for this url, and this will give an error. There are two ways of 'fixing' this. One is by getting a certificate for those subdomains without www too (which seems non useful to me). The other one is by fixing your urls so they actually point to `www.sub.example.com`, not just redirect there.

Comment: all my certificates are valid for the urls with `www.` prefix only. i'm not getting any error when i redirect my main domain from `http://` to `https://www.` or `https://` to `https://www`. The problem persists with the sub-domains only.

Comment: You can't fix a problem with your certificate with `mod_rewrite`. Not afaik at least.

Comment: well it seems that i have to reinstall the certificates once again without www. prefix. thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This single rule should handle your main and sub domains both:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure it is placed as first rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: the mod_rewrite isn't working. It can't redirect the url and displays certificate error. thanks,

Comment: warning will still come because SSL cert negotiation happens before execution of `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: all the certificates were issued in favour of my domains and sub-domains with www. prefix. i don't receive any error when redirect my domain from `https:// to https://www.` using the code i posted in my question. the problem occurs only when i redirect my sub-domains. any idea?

Comment: Warning will not come ONLY if your have cert issued for both `subdomain.domainc.com` AND `www.subdomain.domainc.com`. However if warning is still showing up then look at the reason of the warning to see what exactly it is.